# Purpose of angularjs link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, transclusion

I'm tring to well understand the angularjs link function

I've this example for custom lazy load directive

**script.js:**

```
//Code
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [2,5,23,253];  
});

angular.module('app').directive('myLazyRender', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 900,
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
      var hasBeenShown = false;
      var unwatchFn = scope.$watch(attr.myLazyRender, function(value) {
        if(value && !hasBeenShown) {
          hasBeenShown = true;
          transclude(scope, function(clone) {
            el.after(clone);
          });
          unwatchFn();
        }
      })
    }
  }
})

angular.module('app').directive('echo', function() {
  return {
    priority: 1300,
    link: function() {
      console.log('echo');
    }
  }
})
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1"    rel="stylesheet"   href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1"  src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-rc.4" data-semver="1.3.0-rc.4" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <div my-lazy-render="showit" echo ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item}}
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="showit = true">Render   Content</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

[plunker link example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tdh9wqm2VZivtCZlQXuO?p=preview)

The documentation I've found explains that the link function intent is to create an event listener to handle events

If so, can someone explain the purpose of this event listener and type of event he can listen to in the case of  transclusion of element **‘ tranclude: ‘element’ ’** for this example.

Is there a kind of DOM event to do the binding for **item**

In the example when I click on the **Render Content** Button, the **item** content is loaded.

Comment: The $watch is watching the `my-lazy-render` attribute. In this case `my-lazy-render="showit"`. When the value of `showit` changes to truthy, it renders the contents of the directive by executing the transclude function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the link function sets a watcher on the object passed to the `my-lazy-render` attribute of the `div` element (in this case, `showit`), which executes the function when the value of that object changes. If it changes to true (which is the case when you click the button), it will duplicate the element after the current element (i.e. duplicate the `div` with the `my-lazy-render` attribute).

This duplication is done by the `transclude` function that gets passed to the link function. The `clone` parameter in this case is a copy of the element itself, because transclude is set to `element`.
(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449743/angularjs-when-to-use-transclude-true-and-transclude-element) answer for a little more on transclusion.)

Also, `scope.$watch` returns a function that when called will disable the watcher (i.e. the function will not be executed again when the value changes).