# why angular 1.5 cant create componets to nest html?

Tags: angularjs

Why can't create a component in angularjs like this?

This is important to my because sometime when I buy a template the styles are very big and I need simplify and standardise my code:

This is what I want:

```
<my-component-test>
    <div>
            <h1> this can't be </h1>
    </div>
</my-component-test>
```

this is file my-component-test.html:

```
<div class="etc">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="etc">
                <div class="etc">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is your question about angular.js or angular (2.x.x, 4.x.x) ?

Comment: Your question is especially unclear about if it is about Angular 2-4 or AngularJS 1.x, because you used both tags and nothing in your code makes it clear which one you use.

Comment: Who says you can't? What is the problem? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Hello, I have Angular 1.5

Comment: Hello @Günter Zöchbauer . I need <h1> tag can see it. But when write some code into <my-component-test> tag I cant see it anything

Comment: take a look at ng-transclude https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725399/what-is-ng-transclude and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449743/angularjs-when-to-use-transclude-true-and-transclude-element